# Rough values for the staytime or characteristic length of the combustion chamber of an oxygen/methanol rocket engine?

Tags: rockets, fuel, engine-design, liquid-fuel

I'd like to have some idea of the staytime or characteristic length of the combustion chamber of an oxygen/methanol rocket engine.

Are there sources for this, or a way to estimate it?

I've tried, but so far I am unable to find anything about it on the internet.

Comment: Retracting close vote. Wrong fuel.